# Is one commanded to hear the Ten Commandments on Shavuot?

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, shavuos, aseres-hadibros

Is it really an obligatory mitzvah to hear a reading of the Ten Commandments on the first day of Shavuot (as distinct from the general commandment to hear Torah)? What is the source, if any, for this mitzvah?

Motive: Chabad is very big on this "mitzvah." The Chabad Houses tell people to do it, and Chabad says in one place [online](http://chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2157/jewish/The-Ten-Commandments.htm), "All must attend the reading of the Ten Commandments, men and women, young and old." Is this true?

Comment: I had always understood that it was the same as every other Kri'as HaTorah. Ezra established that we should say certain passages for special occasions related to the day, and thus the Aseres HaDibros are read on Shavuos. I agree with Chabad, that it's very important, but no more so than every other Kri'as HaTorah. (Unless I'm totally off in my understanding of the Mitzvah.)

Comment: SAH, I should have known better that you would be a bit thorough in this question by mentioning Chaba"d, here. I'm throwing a "curve ball" to Chabad's premise. We deduce that the Revelation occurred on 6 Sivan (or, perhaps, the 7th). That would explain reading about an event that occurred on that day. Fine except for one thing ... Shavu'ot is not based on a calendar date, and prior to the fixed calendar, that reading occurred occasionally on 5 Sivan. So, to imply that Shavuot & Mattan Torah coincided is not exactly true.

Comment: @DonielF Share some research with me, perhaps? I am aware that Ezra instituted Torah reading on Shabbat, Mon. and Thurs and, I think Shabbat mincha, also. But, I'm not sure if he instituted reading on Yom Tov. That may be from a different source. Care to research this? I'll see what I can find. If you locate something, I think you should incorporate it as an answer.

Comment: @DanF Good place to start is third Perek of Megillah. I believe the Tosefta only discusses the Haftaros.

Comment: @DanF What a coincidence. Just came across an article that quotes the Rambam in Hilchos Tefillah 13:8 that Moshe Rabbeinu instituted which portions to be read on the chagim, based on the final Gemara in Megillah, but that some portions have been changed by custom (see Megillah 31a regarding Pesach).

Comment: @DonielF I had that suspicion that Ezra wasn't involved with Yom Tov. Thanks. Something for me to read during Shabbat.